# Error with Content Provider

Tags: java, android, database

I'm still learning about programming, and I have a question about a program I'm writing that gives me a strange error.

My app stores 3 Strings in a database, and 1 BLOB (a picture).

The screen is below:

The link to the image is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPxDO.png

The problem I'm having is that you must take a picture first before entering in any of the other data (ie borred item, person name) else the program will crash. If you take the picture first, then there is no problem with filling out the rest.

The code for below is:

```
public class AddItem extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // GUI
    private EditText itemName;
    private AutoCompleteTextView personName;
    private Button setFinish, setDate, camera;
    private TextView getDate; 
    private ImageView window;

    // URI
    private Uri addUri;

    // Date
    private int yr, month, day;

    // DatePicker ID
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;

    // For Camera
    final static int cameraData = 0;
    private Bitmap bmp;

    // ----------------------------------------------------

    public ArrayList<String> contactNameA = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> contactNumberA = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] nameStringArray = null;
    String[] phoneStringArray = null;

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_item);

        // Method Calls -----------------------------------------------------
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        init(); // initialize the parameters

        tabSetter(); // Create the tabs

        calenderSet();

        autoCompleteBox();

        // Listeners --------------------------------------------------------

        setFinish.setOnClickListener(this);

        camera.setOnClickListener(this);

        setDate.setOnClickListener(this);

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        // For pictures ---------
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.take_camera);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        window.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


        addUri = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null : (Uri) savedInstanceState
                .getParcelable(BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

        if (extras != null) {
            addUri = extras
                    .getParcelable(BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

            fillData(addUri);
        }



    }

        // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    private void autoCompleteBox() {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Uri contacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");

        Cursor mCursor = cr.query(contacts, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {

            String nameOfContact;
            String phoneNumberContact;

            int nColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex("name");
            int pColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex("number");
            Log.d("START", "Entering method");
            Log.d("int Name", Integer.toString(nColumn));
            Log.d("int Number", Integer.toString(pColumn));

            do {

                nameOfContact = mCursor.getString(nColumn);
                phoneNumberContact = mCursor.getString(pColumn);
                if ((nameOfContact != " " || nameOfContact != null)
                        && (phoneNumberContact != " " || phoneNumberContact != null)) {

                    contactNameA.add(nameOfContact);
                    contactNumberA.add(phoneNumberContact);


                }

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());

        }

        nameStringArray = (String[]) contactNameA.toArray(new String[contactNameA.size()]);
        phoneStringArray = (String[]) contactNumberA.toArray(new String[contactNameA.size()]);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, nameStringArray);


        personName.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    private void init() {

        personName = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.nameOfPerson);
        itemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.borrowItemFeild);

        setFinish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishThis);

        camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
        window = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageWindow);

        setDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dateChange);
        getDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDate);

    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    @Override
    public void finish() {

        super.finish();
    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, yr, month, day);

        }
        return null;
    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {

            yr = year;
            month = monthOfYear;
            day = dayOfMonth;

            getDate.setText((month + 1) + "/" + day + "/"
                    + year);

            /*
             * Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(), "Date Selected: " + (month + 1)
             * + "/" + day + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             */
        }
    };

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    private void calenderSet() {
        // Call calendar object to get date
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Set the parameters to the current date, so the user doesn't have to
        // scroll from the default date
        yr = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }


    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    // Handles the clicks for all the various views
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case (R.id.finishThis):

            if (personName.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Name can't be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else if (itemName.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Borrowed item can't be blank",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Sets back to tab 0 to ensure user fills out info
                //th.setCurrentTab(0);

            } else if (getDate.getText().toString().equals("Select Date")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                // Sets back to tab 0 to ensure user fills out info
                //th.setCurrentTab(0);

            } else {
                finish();
            }

            break;

        case (R.id.cameraButton):

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);

            break;

        case (R.id.dateChange):

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            break;

        }

    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    private void fillData(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME,
                BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_DATE, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ITEM,  BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_IMAGE};
        Cursor databaseCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                null);
        if (databaseCursor != null) {
            databaseCursor.moveToFirst();


            personName.setText(databaseCursor.getString(databaseCursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME)));
            itemName.setText(databaseCursor.getString(databaseCursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ITEM)));

            getDate.setText(databaseCursor.getString(databaseCursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_DATE)));

            try {
                byte[] imageByteArray = databaseCursor.getBlob(databaseCursor.getColumnIndex(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_IMAGE));
                ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                window.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (Exception e) {


            }
            databaseCursor.close();
        }
    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putParcelable(BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                addUri);
    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    saveState();
    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    private void saveState() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        String date = getDate.getText().toString();
        String item = itemName.getText().toString();
        String name = personName.getText().toString();

        // Only save if either item or person name
        // is available

        if (item.length() == 0 && name.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (bmp == null) {

            values.put(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ITEM, item);
            values.put(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME, name);
            values.put(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_DATE, date);        

        } else {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            values.put(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ITEM, item);
            values.put(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME, name);
            values.put(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_DATE, date);
            values.put(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_IMAGE, byteArray);

        }

        // The resolver statement goes here - moved it into the IF above to see if error is corrected.
        if (addUri == null) {
            // New Entry
            addUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                    BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            // Update Entry
                    getContentResolver().update(addUri, values, null, null);

        }


    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            window.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my content provider:

```
public class BorrowMeContentProvider extends ContentProvider {


    private BorrowMeDatabaseHelper database;


    private static final int BORROWME = 10;
    private static final int BORROWME_ID = 20;

    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.fthatnoise.borrow.me.contentprovider";

    private static final String BASE_PATH = "me";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/" + BASE_PATH);

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
            + "/BORROWME";
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
            + "/BORROWMETYPE";

    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(
            UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    static {
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, BORROWME);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", BORROWME_ID);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        database = new BorrowMeDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {


        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        checkColumns(projection);

        queryBuilder.setTables(BorrowMeTable.DATABASE_TABLE);

        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (uriType) {
        case BORROWME:
            break;
        case BORROWME_ID:

            queryBuilder.appendWhere(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ID + "="
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error in URI: " + uri);
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        return cursor;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
        long id = 0;

        switch (uriType) {
        case BORROWME:
            id = sqlDB.insert(BorrowMeTable.DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error in URI: " + uri);
        }


        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH + "/" + id);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
        int rowsDeleted = 0;
        switch (uriType) {
        case BORROWME:
            rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(BorrowMeTable.DATABASE_TABLE, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
            break;
        case BORROWME_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(BorrowMeTable.DATABASE_TABLE,
                        BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
            } else {
                rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(BorrowMeTable.DATABASE_TABLE,
                        BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id + " and " + selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error in URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsDeleted;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {

        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
        int rowsUpdated = 0;
        switch (uriType) {
        case BORROWME:
            rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(BorrowMeTable.DATABASE_TABLE, values, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
            break;
        case BORROWME_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(BorrowMeTable.DATABASE_TABLE, values,
                        BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
            } else {
                rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(BorrowMeTable.DATABASE_TABLE, values,
                        BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id + " and " + selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error in URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsUpdated;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {
        String[] available = { BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ITEM,
                BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_DATE,
                BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ID, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_IMAGE };
        if (projection != null) {
            HashSet<String> requestedColumns = new HashSet<String>(
                    Arrays.asList(projection));
            HashSet<String> availableColumns = new HashSet<String>(
                    Arrays.asList(available));

            if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Unknown columns in projection");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, the error message I get if I don't take the picture first and attempt to do so after entering in data in any of the text fields -

```
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI me/9
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:988)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at com.fthatnoise.borrow.me.AddItem.saveState(AddItem.java:400)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at com.fthatnoise.borrow.me.AddItem.onSaveInstanceState(AddItem.java:348)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1147)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1216)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3129)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3188)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-30 15:58:21.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It may be something simple, any help would be great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI me/9
    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:988)
```

It appears you have a malformed URI. I'm not the best at ContentProviders but I believe you want to use something like this:

```
URI uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, id);
getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null);
```

Where `id` is the primary key for the row you want to update, in this case `9`.